# How do I use win.disk.duration in Bosun or how do I downsample a counter type metric?

Tags: opentsdb, downsampling, bosun

I'm using Bosun to gather information about the average response time of a hard disk (`win.disk.duration`), it produces a graph such as:

[image]

I understand that this is showing the rate of change of the WMI reported value, `AvgDiskSecPerRead`.

What I want to do is downsample this calculated value taking the max over a time period. However if I set a downsample of `Max` with a window of `5m` I get this:

[image]

Note the Y-axis scale change.

How can I downsample the rate to get the results I'm expecting (or why doesn't what i'm asking for make sense)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently since this is a counter you can't downsample it correctly with OpenTSDB (the datasource I assume you are using due to the question tags). This is because OpenTSDB got the math wrong during design and that hasn't been fixed yet. More information in this [Google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/opentsdb/KdgGNK0Y9HQ). In short, the rate calculation (derivative) needs to be earlier in the order of operations.

Also, be aware that currently on our side (scollector) we seem to have messed up a related metric `win.disk.percent_time` which still has to be looked into (tracked in this [issue](https://github.com/bosun-monitor/bosun/issues/2161)).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and link. Judging by the age of that thread I won't hold my breath.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this transformation is about applying aggregation to the first derivative. Here's an [example](https://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/47b240cd) using `win.disk.duration` metric from scollector but on a different [backend](https://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/writing-data/scollector/).

1. Raw data represents a counter with reset.
2. First derivative calculates the rate of change over a user-defined interval (1 second). Negative delta is handled as a reset by default, but this behavior can be [controlled](https://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/47b240cd/2/) with `rate-counter=true|false` parameter.
3. The aggregation function `max` is applied to the rate over a user-defined period (5 minutes).

I would recommend using 95 percentile function instead of `max` however. The `p95` statistic allows you to [discards](https://apps.axibase.com/chartlab/47b240cd/3/) infrequent spikes from analysis.

[image: rate of change]

Disclaimer: I work for Axibase.